# MSbuild reduce redundant metadata strings

Tags: msbuild

I've written an msbuild props file that looks like this:

```xml
<Target Name="BeforeBuild"
        Inputs="@(XDTConfig -> '%(Filename).template%(Extension)');
                @(XDTConfig -> '%(Filename).$(Configuration)%(Extension)')"
        Outputs="@(XDTConfig)">
<PropertyGroup>
  <XDTSource>@(XDTConfig -> '%(Filename).template%(Extension)')</XDTSource>
  <XDTDest>@(XDTConfig -> '%(Filename)%(Extension)')</XDTDest>
  <XDTTrans>@(XDTConfig -> '%(Filename).$(Configuration)%(Extension)')</XDTTrans>
  <XDTDir>@(XDTConfig -> '%(RootDir)%(Directory)')</XDTDir>
</PropertyGroup>

<Message Importance="High"
         Text="Transforming from $(XDTSource) using $(XDTTrans) to $(XDTDest)..." />

<TransformXml Source="$(XDTDir)$(XDTSource)"
              Destination="@(XDTConfig)"
              Transform="$(XDTDir)$(XDTTrans)" />
</Target>
```

I would prefer to be able to put that property group outside of the target scope to reduce redundancy, but if I do, it seems that none of the properties expand properly. Why can't those properties expand in the project scope instead of the target scope?

---

### Solution based on Lanorkin

```xml
  <!-- File name and path properties -->
  <Target Name="InitMetadata">
    <ItemGroup>
      <XDTConfig Condition="'%(XDTConfig.Identity)' == '%(Identity)'">
        <Source>%(Filename).template%(Extension)</Source>
        <Dest>%(Filename)%(Extension)</Dest>
        <Trans>%(Filename).$(Configuration)%(Extension)</Trans>
        <Dir>%(RootDir)%(Directory)</Dir>
      </XDTConfig>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <!-- Target to transform the config file if necessary -->
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild"
          DependsOnTargets="InitMetadata"
          Outputs="@(XDTConfig)"
          Inputs="'%(Source)';'%(Trans)'">

    <!-- Show what's going on -->
    <Message Importance="High"
             Text="Transforming from @(XDTConfig -> '%(Source) using %(Trans) to %(Dest)')..." />

    <!-- Do the actual transform (silent) -->
    <TransformXml Destination="@(XDTConfig)"
                  Source="%(Dir)%(Source)"
                  Transform="%(Dir)%(Trans)" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not reaaly sure what you are trying to do..

But looks like you need to understand differences between `Property`, `Item` and `Item Metadata`

- `Property` referred by `$` and contains single value
- `Item` referred by `@` and can be though about as **Array**, which can contain multiple values
- `Item metadata` is referred by `%` and can be thought of as some kind of **Dictionary** which comes with each `Item`

So, if you try to declare PropertyGroup in the Project scope, you may not include array in it - but looks like it's what you want to do.

You may try to associate Item Metadata to your existing Items, and when just use this metadata in any targets.

Here is working sample for msbuild 4 (previous versions have own magic):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <!-- Dummy initializations -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <XDTConfig Include="item1.ext1" />
    <XDTConfig Include="item1.ext2" />
    <XDTConfig Include="item2.ext2" />
    <XDTConfig Include="item2.ext3" />
    <XDTConfig Include="item3.ext3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="InitMetadata">
    <!-- Assigning custom metadata to already existing items -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <XDTConfig Condition="'%(XDTConfig.Identity)' == '%(Identity)'">
        <XDTSource>%(Filename).template%(Extension)</XDTSource>
        <XDTDest>%(Filename)%(Extension)</XDTDest>
        <XDTTrans>%(Filename).$(Configuration)%(Extension)</XDTTrans>
        <XDTDir>%(RootDir)%(Directory)</XDTDir>
      </XDTConfig>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="InitMetadata">
    <!-- Here we use item metadata for batching Message target -->
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Transform: Source = %(XDTConfig.XDTDir)%(XDTConfig.XDTSource), Destination = @(XDTConfig), Transform = %(XDTConfig.XDTDir)%(XDTConfig.XDTTrans)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

And here is Message task output (`D:\temp\msbuild\` is working dir):

```
Transform: Source = D:\temp\msbuild\item1.template.ext1, Destination = item1.ext1, Transform = D:\temp\msbuild\item1.Debug.ext1
Transform: Source = D:\temp\msbuild\item1.template.ext2, Destination = item1.ext2, Transform = D:\temp\msbuild\item1.Debug.ext2
Transform: Source = D:\temp\msbuild\item2.template.ext2, Destination = item2.ext2, Transform = D:\temp\msbuild\item2.Debug.ext2
Transform: Source = D:\temp\msbuild\item2.template.ext3, Destination = item2.ext3, Transform = D:\temp\msbuild\item2.Debug.ext3
Transform: Source = D:\temp\msbuild\item3.template.ext3, Destination = item3.ext3, Transform = D:\temp\msbuild\item3.Debug.ext3
```

Comment: Sweet!

1. Please explain what the identity check does
2. Please comment on the validity of my edited post (I managed to simplify the solution a little bit)

Comment: 1. I just get used to it, it's not really required here. Basically, when I use %(..) notation, I made msbuild to use task batching, thus forcing it to re-calculate values for each Item. Otherwise it just assigns the same value to all Item.MetadataID. Again, here is it not the case. 2. Look OK )